# Assign converted html to a serverside control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using markdown and I've got some input such as `**test**` which makes the word test appear in bold **test** and I've converted it with html like so"

```
                var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
                var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
                editor1.run();

                var d = document.getElementById("wmd_input");
                var html = converter1.makeHtml(d.value);
                alert(html);
```

And this alerts `<b>test</b>` the issue is I need to take this value, namely `<b>test</b>` and access this via server side code (asp.net).  I tried assigning it to a variable like so:

```
                document.getElementById("Label1").value = html;
```

But it doesn't seem to work, when I go to the code behind it shows `Label1` as being empty.
Is this possible?

### Edit

I tried to change it to a hidden field same issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                (function () {
                    var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
                    var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
                    editor1.run();

                    var d = document.getElementById("wmd_input");
                    var html = converter1.makeHtml(d.value);
                    alert(html);

                    document.getElementById('<%= h1.ClientID %>').value = html;
                    var h = document.getElementById('<%= h1.ClientID %>');
                    alert(h.value);
                })();
            </script>
```

The issue I have is I have an asp.net server side button that when clicked I try to do this:

`Label1.Text = h1.Value;`

That is to store the value from the hidden field to a label but this doesnt work.  When I put a break point in it shows `h1` is empty `""`....So I'm not sure what event or how to do this so that when I make changes to my textarea `wmd_input` that i should be able to see these changes in my server side code...

Here's my entire asp.net form:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PageDown Demo Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Markdown.Sanitizer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" runat="server">
            <div class="wmd-panel">
                <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
                <textarea cols="5" rows="5" id="wmd_input" class="wmd-input" runat="server"></textarea>
                <div id="wmd_preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview" runat="server"></div>
            </div>
            <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Set" onclick="Button1_Click"></asp:button>
            <asp:button id="Button2" runat="server" Text="Get" onclick="Button2_Click"></asp:button><asp:label id="Label1" runat="server">Label</asp:label>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="h1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function () {
                    var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
                    var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
                    editor1.run();

                    var d = document.getElementById("wmd_input");
                    var html = converter1.makeHtml(d.value);
                    alert(html);

                    document.getElementById('<%= h1.ClientID %>').value = html;
                    alert(document.getElementById('<%= h1.ClientID %>').value);
                })();
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `asp:Label` tag isn't an input control, so it won't get posted back to the server.  I'd suggest using `asp:HiddenField` or `asp:TextBox` instead.  (And Adil's point is crucial too, you need to make sure the client ID is actually what you think it is.)

---

Here's a test that works for me.  On the first page load, the label shows "initial value", but the alert shows "updated".  After postback, the label also shows "updated".

**Edit** Added the client-side update logic inside a client-side event handler.

```
<%@ Page Title="Test" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load()
    {
        l1.Text = h1.Value;
    }
</script>

<html>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value="initial value" ID="h1" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="l1" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="do postback" />
    </form>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID %>').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('<%= h1.ClientID %>').value = 'updated';
            alert(document.getElementById('<%= h1.ClientID %>').value);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right you are correct on label but I tried using a hidden field and its the same issue `document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value = html;
           var h = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
           alert(h.value);`

Comment: @oJM86o it's probably an issue in the flow of your code.  See my update for a short working example -- I'd suggest you try something like this to isolate the issue.

Comment: @oJM86o is your script block at the top of the page?  That could explain what you're seeing.  Try moving it to the bottom ...

Comment: I understand your code, the issue is lets say I type a word in like "test" and I click an asp.net submit button (Server side button) and do something like this:  `Label1.Text = h1.Value;` the issue is h1.Value is still empty even though I typed in "test".  That is is my issue.

Comment: @oJM86o so you're trying to set the hidden field on the client using a server-side callback?  Please try and boil your question down to a short, self-contained example.  See here:  http://sscce.org/

Comment: Sorry it is very difficult to explain sometimes.  Lets make this real simple...My page opens up it shows a textarea with the id `wmd_input`.  Lets say I type in the word "test" in this textarea and I click a serverside asp.net button.  This in turn goes to the "click" event of this server side button.  Now when I debug and look at `Label1.Text = h1.Value` meanining if I try to assign the hidden field value to the label1 it shows h1 (my hidden field) as not having a value `""`.  So nothing happens...now lets say I click that server side button again..now in the code behind...

Comment: ...(continued)..now in the code behind I can see the value "test" in my hidden field and I can assign it to my label.  But the issue is lets say I type in something again like "test 2" and click the button, again it only remembers the prior value "test" and it doesnt see "test 2" until I click the button again

Comment: +1 so far for at least following me...would it be easier to show you in chat ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19107/discussion-between-ojm86o-and-dbaseman)

Comment: @oJM86o looks like my work is blocking the chat feature ... I think maybe you just need a client-side handler for the button, to update before the postback.  But now I'm starting to wonder if you even need the server involved at all: couldn't you just update the label from Javascript, and cut out the middleman (the server)?

Comment: Im just doing this for a test, eventually I need the server to take the HTML and send to a database...I wonder if I just need an `onchange()` event for my wmd_input textbox and just do something like this: `function changeme() {
                    var d = document.getElementById("wmd_input");
                    var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
                    var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
                    var html = converter1.makeHtml(d.value);
                document.getElementById('<%= h1.ClientID %>').value = html;
                }`

Comment: @oJM86o see my updated example.  I think you probably just want to put your Javascript logic inside a click handler.  That way, the value in `h1` will get updated *before* the postback to the server.

Comment: @oJM86o yes, that should work too, but it would update after each keystroke.  I suspect you want to run the markdown processing after the user hits "go", right?

Comment: You are absolutely correct sir, that would be more efficient.  My javascript is really bad but this is clicking thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Labels don't post. You will have to use an `input` or `textarea` element ([`<asp:TextBox>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx)). If you don't want the user to see the markup source, you can also use an [`<asp:HiddenField>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx).

Comment: I tried using an asp:hiddenfield but see my edit in my question, its still the same issue.

Comment: Is your javascript tag after your hidden field tag? You could also try running script in the body onload event.

Comment: I understand your code, the issue is lets say I type a word in like "test" and I click an asp.net submit button (Server side button) and do something like this: Label1.Text = h1.Value; the issue is h1.Value is still empty even though I typed in "test". That is is my issue

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do what you want to do by using knockoutjs http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html  You can use element binding.